# Extracting a variable value from a multi-line MQTT message with C++

Tags: c++, serial-port, mqtt, at-command

My microcontroller is receiving an MQTT message through a UART connection to a cellular modem in response to an AT command, the response I am getting looks like:

```
21:25:42.224 -> AT+QMTPUBEX=1,0,0,0,"motorbeta/heartbeat","{"pulse":1,"secondary":2}"
21:25:42.224 -> OK
21:25:42.224 -> 
21:25:42.224 -> +QMTPUB: 1,0,0
21:25:42.224 -> 
21:25:42.224 -> +QMTRECV: 1,0,"motorbeta/shutdown","shutdown=1"
```

I am sending the command and recording the response on the serial monitor using some c++ which looks like:

```
//AT command sequences
void atsendbasic(String command, int fallout3, int fallout4){
   unsigned long initialtime4 = millis();
   Serial2.print(command);
   Serial2.flush();  // Wait until it is all sent
    while ((!Serial2.available() && millis() - initialtime4 <= fallout3) || millis() - initialtime4 <= fallout4) continue;
    while ((Serial2.available()&& millis() - initialtime4 <= fallout3) || millis() - initialtime4 <= fallout4) {
      char feedback = Serial2.read();
      Serial.print(feedback);
    }
}
```

But I need to store the value in the last line of the MQTT response in a global integer variable named shutdown.  What I have so far should work for 1 line responses, like when I run with just `+QMTRECV: 1,0,"motorbeta/shutdown","shutdown=1"` as the input, but doesn't work for multi line responses.

```
int shutdown;
int
getValue (char *s,const char *lbl,int  *val ){
    char fmt [40];
    sprintf (fmt, "%s=", lbl);

    char *q = strstr (s, fmt);
    if (NULL == q)
        return 0;

    sprintf (fmt, "%s=%%d", lbl);
    sscanf (q, fmt, val);
    return 1;
}
void atreceivebasic(String command, int fallout3, int fallout4){
   char feedback;
   unsigned long initialtime5 = millis();
   Serial2.print(command);
   Serial2.flush();  // Wait until it is all sent
    while ((!Serial2.available() && millis() - initialtime5 <= fallout3) || millis() - initialtime5 <= fallout4) continue;
    while ((Serial2.available()&& millis() - initialtime5 <= fallout3) || millis() - initialtime5 <= fallout4) {
      feedback = Serial2.read();
      Serial.print(feedback);
    }
     getValue ((char*)feedback, "shutdown", &shutdown);
     Serial.println(shutdown);
}
```

I am having trouble modifying this C++ to incorporate multi line responses, mostly because I don't fully understand how it works for the single line example.  Can someone help me solve this problem.

Comment: Read the characters to form a line terminated by a CR control character.  Append a NUL character to form a string.  Use string matching functions to perform a lexical scan and/or parsing to identify the type of response and its information.  If you're using a POSIX OS such as Linux, then learn how to perform canonical reads (i.e. have the OS return a line rather than an arbitrary quantity of bytes).